# Turn off a warning in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy with reflection, a couple of partial indices in my DB make it dump warnings like this:

`SAWarning: Predicate of partial index i_some_index ignored during reflection`

into my logs and keep cluttering. It does not hinder my application behavior. I would like to keep these warnings while developing, but not at production level. Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Python's [warning module](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) provides a handy [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#available-context-managers) that catches warnings for you.

Here's how to filter out the SQLAlchemy warning.

```
import warnings
from sqlalchemy import exc as sa_exc

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=sa_exc.SAWarning)
    # code here...
```

As for development vs production, you can just have this warning wrap around your application's entry point or an external script that invokes your application in your production environment.

Usually, I solve this by having an environment variable that executes a slightly different code path than when developing, for example, wrapping around different middleware etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Though, I wonder if it can be turn of in some sense?

Comment: This is brilliant. Python has everything!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The warning still pops up: usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1364, "Field 'external_id' doesn't have a default value")

Comment: I figured out my issue. It's not a "sa_exc.SAWarning". I just need to remove the category, then the warning can be suppressed.

Answer (score 14):

the warning means you did a table or metadata reflection, and it's reading in postgresql indexes that have some complex condition which the SQLAlchemy reflection code doesn't know what to do with.   This is a harmless warning, as whether or not indexes are reflected doesn't affect the operation of the application, unless you wanted to re-emit CREATE statements for those tables/indexes on another database.

Comment: Thanks. I know they're harmless, my application works very good. But each time the daemon restarts, these warnings are sent to my apache error log and they clutter. Is there a way to actually turn off index reflection all-together?

Comment: I think the suggestion to tune your warnings filter at the start is a good idea here.  We do this via warnings for this purpose.   There's no option for the index reflection right now (though not terribly hard to implement).

Comment: OK, I'll go with the answer above, probably catch the warnings in the part where I do the reflection. The index reflection is really no significant overhead, so I wouldn't give it much effort :) Thanks a lot!