# SQLAlchemy: How to traverse bindparam values in a subquery?

Tags: python, caching, sqlalchemy, subquery

I'm trying to extract SQLAlchemy query parameter values for use in caching, using the function `_params_from_query` from the [SQLAlchemy Beaker Caching example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#beaker-caching).

Unfortunately when I try it with a query involving a subquery, it seems to only traverse the main query parameters, ignoring the subquery.

The following example code demonstrates this when run from the `beaker_cache` example folder in the SQLAlchemy distribution.

```
from environment import Session
from model import Person
from caching_query import _params_from_query

s = Session.query(Person.name).filter(Person.name=="subquery value").subquery()

q = Session.query(s.c.name).filter(s.c.name=="main query value")

print q.params()
print 
print _params_from_query(q)

# SELECT anon_1.name AS anon_1_name 
# FROM (SELECT person.name AS name 
# FROM person 
# WHERE person.name = :name_1) AS anon_1    <- two
# WHERE anon_1.name = :name_2               <- parameters
#
# ['main query value']    <- only one value
```

Am I using the function incorrectly? How can I get the parameter values from the subquery as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a bug in the example.   Here's a workaround that should get everything (though I'd like to improve this to not require the full statement compilation):

```
diff -r affaa93fad92 examples/beaker_caching/caching_query.py
--- a/examples/beaker_caching/caching_query.py  Tue Feb 14 10:16:16 2012 -0500
+++ b/examples/beaker_caching/caching_query.py  Tue Feb 14 11:57:59 2012 -0500
@@ -268,8 +268,5 @@
             value = bind.value

         v.append(value)
-    if query._criterion is not None:
-        visitors.traverse(query._criterion, {}, {'bindparam':visit_bindparam})
-    for f in query._from_obj:
-        visitors.traverse(f, {}, {'bindparam':visit_bindparam})
+    visitors.traverse(query.statement, {}, {'bindparam':visit_bindparam})
     return v
```

Comment: That works great. I also decided to wrap the ``traverse`` in a [block that catches warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225951/201665) because I kept getting the warning ``Column ... on table ... being replaced by another column with the same key.`` for any queries that contained a ``joinedload``.

Comment: oh, there's ways to make it not do that...you'd say query.with_labels().statement